# Generate skeleton method bodies in implementation files in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, skeleton-code

In Xcode, for Obj-C programs, is there a way to generate skeleton method body in the .m file if I add a new method or implement an interface in the corresponding .h file? Like in Eclipse, if you implement an interface, it will bring in the method skeleton according to the definition of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

if you do a lot of OS X/iOS development, the best option i know of (for objc) is Accessorizer.app.